# Facebook "send" button does not display on page

Tags: facebook, widget, send

I have added the Facebook Send button to my website and it does not display. Has Facebook turned off the Send feature?

[Here is the page in question.](http://compesh.com/test2.html)

[The documentation for the Facebook Share widget is here.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/send-button)

Below is the code for the html page

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Your Website Title</title>
    <!-- You can use open graph tags to customize link previews.
    Learn more: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters -->
  <meta property="og:url"           content="https://www.your-domain.com/your-page.html" />
  <meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
  <meta property="og:title"         content="Your Website Title" />
  <meta property="og:description"   content="Your description" />
  <meta property="og:image"         content="https://www.your-domain.com/path/image.jpg" />
</head>
<body>

  <!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    // js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
    js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.12&appId=299539706821986&autoLogAppEvents=1';
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

  <!-- Your send button code -->
  <div class="fb-send" 
    data-href="https://compesh.com/test2.html" 
    data-layout="button_count">
  </div>
  <div class="fb-send" data-href="https://compesh.com"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It doesn’t even work in the generator in the documentation, so I guess this is either currently broken, or they have removed it.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/send-button

> With the release of Graph API version 2.11, the Send Button is
>   deprecated. For Graph API versions 2.10 and under, the Send Button
>   will be supported until February 5, 2018.